# Is there a standard icon for the Facebook Feed Dialog?

Tags: facebook, icons, share, facebook-wall, facebook-timeline

I want to add the Facebook feed dialog to my website. What is the common practice for the clickable 'thing' that a user sees in order to invoke this dialog? I can think of a few possibilities:

1. I've seen a little green square with a pair of quotes in it. Google finds that when I search for 'post to wall icon' - but 'wall' seems outdated now, isn't it all about the timeline?
2. The blue button with 'share' written in a white font. Again, I've read that 'share' is an older concept.
3. An ultra boring text link like 'Post to your timeline' (come on, there has to be a recognizable icon :) )